# -[UITextMultiTapRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance at iOS 13.4 and above

Tags: objective-c, swift, webview, ios13.4

My app is based on WebView. It's a pretty old app written on Objective C.

When I click on the same text field, the application crashes. But if I switch between text fields, then everything is fine. 
When I click on the same text box again, the application crashes.

I get only one error: -**[UITextMultiTapRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x119d6d640**

This only happens on iOS 13.4 and above. 
I can’t understand where I can catch the double click that the application receives?

I could not find any information in Google except this post at Apple Developer Forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/130636

No one knows what does it mean **UITextMultiTapRecognizer**

I would really appreciate for advice.

Add a screenshot of logs with an extension breakpoint

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting an exception breakpoint?

Comment: I'll check.. Thanks

Comment: Is that your swizzling? If so, what happens if you disable that.

Comment: Is it a UIWebView?

Comment: @matt Yes. And there is a form, not native.

Comment: UIWebView is deprecated and unsupported. Replace it with WKWebView.

Comment: @matt thank you for your response. It's not my app. And yes I suggested to replace it with WKWebView. But for me interesting that I've faced with an error that didn't happen before. And t's happen just from iOS 13.4. Weird...